# How do ADO.NET DataTable Constraints affect performance?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Do constraints on a DataTable (e.g. PrimaryKey & UniqueContraint) make Selects more efficient in the same way that they would in SQL Server? Or is their only purpose to enforce rules on the data?

```
myDT.Constraints.Add("PK", myDT.Columns["UniqueID"], true); //add a primary key
myDT.Constrinats.Add(new UniqueConstraint(new DataColumn[] { //add a unique constraint for UserID
    myDT.Columns["UserID"], myDT.Columns["UniqueID"]
}));
```

Would these examples potentially have better performance when looking up data in the DataTable by `UniqueID` or `UserID`?

Comment: I think revision #2 is the correct title, Terrapin. "Affect" is a better word than "effect" in this case. I see that you've been going back and forth between the two, so I'll leave it up to you to edit it if you agree.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing the use of primary keys and constraints (business domain model) with the use of indexes (performance).

A Foreign Key can influence an optimiser, and it is common to create an index on Foreign keys.

In the SQL Server world, a Primary key is often confused with a Clustered index, because more often than than a surrogate key (think auto-increment identity column) is choosen as the Primary Key and Clustered Index.

This article may be of interest: [DataSet and DataTable in ADO.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163709.aspx).

In response to your comment:

> **Use a DataView for Repetitive Non-Primary Key Searches**  If you
>   need to repetitively search by using
>   non-primary key data, create a
>   DataView that has a sort order. This
>   creates an index that can be used to
>   perform the search. This is best
>   suited to repetitive searches because
>   there is some cost to creating the
>   index.
>
> The DataView object exposes the Find
>   and FindRows methods so that you can
>   query the data in the underlying
>   DataTable. If you are only performing
>   a single query, the processing that is
>   required to create the index reduces
>   the performance that is gained by
>   using the index.
>
> When you create a DataView object, use
>   the DataView constructor that takes
>   the Sort, RowFilter, and
>   RowStateFilter values as constructor
>   arguments along with the underlying
>   DataTable. Using the DataView
>   constructor ensures that the index is
>   built once. If you create an empty
>   DataView and set the Sort, RowFilter,
>   or RowStateFilter properties
>   afterwards, the index is built at
>   least two times.

Comment: Is there a way to add an index to an ADO.NET DataTable that would give me an efficient lookup on those columns?

I didn't see one, hence the UniqueConstraint, which in SQL Server would give me an implicit index. I just don't know if the same efficiency translates to .NET.

Comment: You should benchmark it and see for yourself if it creates an improvement in your situation.  The results may surprise you.

Answer (score 0):

In general constraints slow things down. But for selects the unique constraint can speed things up (but I can find a MS reference), also it may be limited based on the select. Most of the references I find talk about the constraints slowing things down.

So in your case it could improve performance.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49z48hxc.aspx

Comment: I did find this:
http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.adonet/2006-03/msg00379.html

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable`s are implemented using [B-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-Tree) (or some variation thereof). A quick peek into Reflector shows that there's an `Index` class plus `LiveIndexes` property in a `DataTable` class, which implies there are some indexes, but I don't really know where they are.

From my (truly limited) experience: queries on PK are really fast.