# Indexing a datatable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, indexing, dataview

I have a `Datatable` which contains millions of data.

**DATATABLE : Before creating Index**

```
x--------------------------------x
|     DateColumn        |  Name  |
x-----------------------|--------x
| 2014-01-02 10:01:03   |    A   | 
| 2014-01-02 11:07:23   |    A   |
| 2014-01-03 07:12:15   |    A   |
| 2014-01-15 11:01:03   |    B   |
| 2014-01-16 13:17:23   |    B   |
| 2014-01-16 22:22:15   |    B   |
|          .            |    .   |
|          .            |    .   |
|          .            |    .   |
x-----------------------|--------x
```

When I query from the above table for a particular `Name`, it takes almost 7 seconds to retrieve records using `datatable.Select`.

```
foreach(DataRow dr in datatable1.Select("Name='C'"))
{

}
```

I searched a lot and found that creating a column with `AutoIncrement` and sorting that column with a `DataView` will improve performance. Here is the code I tried.

```
datatable1.Columns["Id"].AutoIncrement = true;
datatable1.Columns["Id"].AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
ReadFromCSV(); // Method thatread from CSV file and inserts to datatable1.    
DataView dv = new DataView(datatable1);
dv.Sort = "Id ASC";
datatable1= dv.ToTable();
```

Now it takes only 4 seconds to retrieve records using `datatable.Select`. Now my question is : 
 **`IS THERE A WAY TO CREATE NON-CLUSTERED INDEX FOR A COLUMN IN DATATABLE TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE ADDITIONALLY?`**

Comment: Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364983.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012726/how-do-ado-net-datatable-constraints-affect-performance

Comment: I read the data from a **Comma Separated Value** file @Scott Chamberlain

Comment: Ah my mistake, you are using a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not a Database. Datatables don't do indexes themselves, you would have to write your own implementation. You might benifit from using a lightweight database in your program to hold your data so you can use it to create indexes.

Comment: Yes. I have written own implementation as if it will work like **CLUSTERED INDEX**. I need to additionally add up performance(as if it should work like **NON CLUSTERED INDEX** @Scott Chamberlain

Comment: And I am telling you a DataTable can't do that. You need to use a diffrent data structure or load the data in to a lightweight database like [Sql Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact)

Comment: Now you still need to explain why adding an auto-id column should help you when filtering by name...

Comment: I don't know that. But the performance got increased by doing so and applying a DataView. @Thorsten Dittmar

Comment: Not possible. Must be something else. What you describe is like saying "going through all the entries from the beginning to end is significantly slower than going through all the entries from end to beginning". It is simply not possible and must have other reasons.

Comment: K. Thank you :) @Thorsten Dittmar

Comment: Sir. Do you have any updates for my question? @Jon Skeet